# Simulink's find_system returns an empty array

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have some problem with the function [`find_system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) in MATLAB.

I would like to get a list of all the transfer functions present in my Simulink model. I have tried to do this:

```
find_system(sys,'BlockType','Transfer Fcn')
```

But the output is like this:

```
ans = Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```

This is impossible because I have 3 continuous transfer functions!

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that 'Transfer Fcn' is a valid 'BlockType'?

Comment: I don't know. How I can realize what you say?

Comment: How many 'BlockType' exist?

Comment: Use `get_param` on one of your tffs to see what is its actual 'BlockType'.

Comment: In any case even also I try to write something like this:   find_system(sys,'BlockType','bsauikcnipaachks') matlab says ans = Empty cell array: 0-by-1. This means that this function is not so good itself.

Comment: Have you tried an "empty call" to `find_system`, see the doc.

Comment: I know this type of command: get_param('modello/Transfer Fcn','DialogParameters') but it tells parameters of my tff

Comment: I don't know how to do an "empty call" with find_sytem

Comment: Thanks CST-Link I have used "Explore" on my ftt and under the type "BlockType" I read "TransferFcn" so I get wrong typing "Transfer Fcn" with the space in the middle!!

Comment: Thanks to everybody!!!!! great job :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlockType for a Transfer Function block is 'TransferFcn'.

[Note:
To find out the BlockType of any Simulink Block, add that block to your model, click on it and do this:

```
type = get_param(gcb,'BlockType');
```

]

so now, open your model (click on it anywhere) and type this:

```
transfunc = find_system(gcs,'BlockType','TransferFcn')
```

you can also use model name instead of gcs.

Hope this helps :)